# Is there a way to find out how long a tab has been open, or when a tab opened?

Tags: firefox, time

I'm trying to find a way to show how long a particular tab has been open in Firefox. Alternatively, finding out when a tab was opened would work as I could calculate the open time myself. I'm willing to install extensions, etc. Instructions for other browsers would be appreciated as well, in case there's no way to do this in Firefox. This seems pretty simple, but I haven't been able to find anything after extensive searching. Help!

Comment: I know about this Chrome extension that can do what you're asking for - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/time-tracker/mokmnbikneoaenmckfmgjgjimphfojkd?hl=en There is a bookmarklet that can track time but you'll have to start it for each tab that you want to track - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/01/browsing-time-tracker-bookmarklet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, I found a slightly different solution. In the addon, Simple Timer, there's a timer that shows how long a browser session has been open. So I can use this to find out how long a particular browser window has been open. It's not quite as fine grained as per tab, but it works for my purposes and doesn't require me to calculate anything or start a timer.

Answer (score 7):

In Firefox:

- History
- Show All History
- Views
- Show Columns
- Most Recent Visit

Works on all open tabs and tabs that have been closed, as long as you don't clear history often.

Comment: Thanks, although that's a lot more steps then I was hoping for, and I'll have to locate the URL in the history. Ideally I'd just like to see the information about the current tab that's active.

Comment: Does it need to be hidden?  There is an addon for Firefox that will give you stats on how long you have been on certain tabs, but it is clearly visible on Firefox, plus I believe if you're not looking at the tabs, it doesn't record the time.  So for example if I have 3 tabs open, but don't look at the other 2, it won't record how long those tabs have been open, but only how long I've been on each specific tab.(hopefully that makes sense.)  It is called "Mind The Tab" if you want to try it out yourself and see if it would be a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for something that kept track of how long it had been open, not just how long it had been active. Also, are you speaking of Mind the Time? Because I can't find anything called Mind the Tab.

Comment: Yeah I was, my apologies!  Outside of these two things, I am not sure how to give you what you're asking, hopefully someone else has an idea.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 4):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815069). Basically, use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:alert(new Date(performance.timing.navigationStart).toString())
```

Or more specifically, as a duration (using a combination of answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss/19300106)):

```
javascript:var d = new Date().getTime() - performance.timing.navigationStart; alert(Math.floor(d/(24*60*60*1000))+" days, "+new Date(d).toISOString().substr(11,8))
```

Type the 'j' and paste the rest into the address bar, as browser security measures automatically remove the `javascript:` prefix, and might, if you then press enter, (annoyingly) turn it into a search, which will navigate away from the target page and make it useless.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Firefox addon [Load Time by Nobuyuki Honda](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/load-time/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)

But as other people said above, checking the day of the History open tabs its the ideal solution!